# Finding Coprime triplets

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, divisibility

Given a sequence a1, a2, ..., aN. Count the number of triples (i, j, k) such that 1 ≤ i < j < k ≤ N and GCD(ai, aj, ak) = 1. Here GCD stands for the Greatest Common Divisor.

Example : Let N=4 and array be :

1 2 3 4

Here answer is 4.

I want to calculate it if N is upto 10^5.

Comment: solution: https://discuss.codechef.com/t/coprime3-editorial/6051

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, this doesn't answer the question at hand, but one that is perhaps closely enough related to give some ideas on how to proceed.

At https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=2889 Guego has written,

"It's quite easy to count the number $C(n)$ of triples $(a,b,c)$ with $1\leq a,b,c \leq n$ which are coprime ($\gcd(a,b,c)=1$).

"Indeed, using the formula $n^3 = \sum_d C(n/d)$, we can have $C(n)$ quite easily using a recursive algorithm, or with the Möbius inversion formula.

"I implemented it in python, and my program gives, for example, $$C(1000000) = 831907430687799769$$ in less than one second."

Guego later adds, "the sum is over all the possible values of $d$ (not just the divisors of $n$), but $n/d$ must be understood as an integer division."

Comment: PLease explain it a bit,.Whats d here?

Comment: Note that the $a_i$ in the OP are not the integers $[1,N]$ which you have used.

Comment: Eric, absolutely right --- I read too fast. Will edit.

Comment: $d$ is a dummy variable --- it runs over the integers.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume absolutely nothing about the $\{a_i\}_{i=1}^N$...

Make a graph.  The set of vertices of the graph, $V$, are the $a_i$.  Add an edge between the vertices $a_i$ and $a_j$ labelled $\gcd(a_i,a_j)$.  It is convenient to keep the collection of edges, $E$, and also, for each distinct $\gcd$ the set of labels having that $\gcd$, call it $E_g$ for $g \in \{\gcd(a_i,a_j) \mid a_i,a_j \in V\}$.

For each edge $e \in E$, labelled $t$, construct the graph with edges $e$ and the union of all the $E_g$ with $\gcd(g,t)=1$.  (It may be helpful to construct the graph of pairs of $E_g$ that have relatively prime labels and cache these unions, since you may need them many times.)  [Count the number of triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117024/complexity-of-counting-the-number-of-triangles-of-a-graph) in this constructed graph.  (Note that the adjacency matrices used at the given link are the unions of the adjacency matrices for the various $E_g$.)  Accumulate these counts for each $e$ to get the total count of coprime triples.

This algorithm can easily take $O(N^3)$ time and $O(N^2)$ space.  The trivial solution (not described here) also takes $O(N^3)$ time but only $O(1)$ space.  In spite of this, I expect the above to be much faster than the trivial solution given the amount of redundant work it avoids.

Aside:  My first try at a solution counted triples of edges with label "1", but this is incorrect since $\{6,10,15\}$ would not be found by this method, assuming those integers are in the $a_i$.