# Count pairwise coprime triples such that the maximum number of the triple is not greater than N

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, graph-theory, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

**Problem Statement:**

Given N you are to count the number of pairwise coprime triples which satisfy $1≤a,b,c≤N$.

**Example:**

For example N=3,
valid triples are (1,1,1),(1,1,2),(1,2,1),(2,1,1),(1,1,3),(1,3,1),(3,1,1),(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,2,1),(3,1,2)

Hence answer for N=3 is 13.

Source: own problem.

**Solution so far:**

I have found the oeis series [A256390](https://oeis.org/A256390)  but Reyna & Heyman's work seems too overwhelming for me to understand.If someone can explain that in simple terms with an example it would be great or if you have an alternate solution you are welcome too.

I have found a solution. I will move the following to answer once I have better understanding. For now documenting my understandings here:

I found a [code](https://ideone.com/QuEKuU) ([modified](https://ideone.com/jTDLB2))
This is a deterministic approach and had nothing to do with Reyna & Heyman's approximation.
For N=6 answer should be 64 .

Now let's see his implementation. He's constructing graph with just 7 edges

[image]

```
I:mu[1] * f[1] * f[1] * f[1]=216
I:mu[2] * f[2] * f[2] * f[2]=-27
I:mu[3] * f[3] * f[3] * f[3]=-8
I:mu[4] * f[4] * f[4] * f[4]=0
I:mu[5] * f[5] * f[5] * f[5]=-1
I:mu[6] * f[6] * f[6] * f[6]=1
3B:(mu[1] * f[2] + mu[2] * f[1]) * f[2] * f[2]=-27
3B:(mu[1] * f[3] + mu[3] * f[1]) * f[3] * f[3]=-16
3B:(mu[1] * f[5] + mu[5] * f[1]) * f[5] * f[5]=-5
3B:(mu[1] * f[6] + mu[6] * f[1]) * f[6] * f[6]=7
3B:(mu[2] * f[3] + mu[3] * f[2]) * f[6] * f[6]=-5
3B:(mu[2] * f[6] + mu[6] * f[2]) * f[6] * f[6]=2
3B:(mu[3] * f[6] + mu[6] * f[3]) * f[6] * f[6]=1
6A:mu[3] * mu[2] * mu[1] * 1 * 3 * mark[1]=6
6A:mu[6] * mu[2] * mu[1] * 1 * 3 * mark[1]=-3
6A:mu[6] * mu[3] * mu[1] * 1 * 2 * mark[1]=-2
6A:mu[6] * mu[3] * mu[2] * 1 * 1 * mark[2]=1
```

Ans=(216-27-8+0-1+1)+3*(-27-16-5+7-5+2+1)+6*(6-3-2+1)=64

**gcd(a,b,c)=1 Case:**

I have labelled 3 sections of the program with `I:`,`3B:`,`6A:` tags.
For [gcd(a,b,c)=1](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?t=2889) problem `I:` tags are after which we stop.
We don't need `3B:` or `6A:` tags. We neither need to construct the graph nor traverse it. And it indeed clocks less than a sec for n=1000000.

But for `pairwise gcd=1` problem we need to exclude/include more scenarios.So lets proceed.

**gcd(a,b)>1 or gcd(b,c)>1 or gcd(c,a)>1 Case:**

For each of the items labelled `3B:` he adds an edge from first `mu` node to first `f` node with weight equal to either of first f[i] value outside the first pathesis.
[image]

in `3B:(mu[1] * f[2] + mu[2] * f[1]) * f[2] * f[2]`
`(mu[1] * f[2] + mu[2] * f[1])` part is for selecting an item in a column which is not multiple of `2`.wile the other two columns have multiple of `2`.`3` in `3B` is C(3 1) for permuting this column either at start , middle or end.

Essentially for all pair of factors of `i` we draw edge from smaller factor to larger factor with weight `f[i]`.If the edge already exist we skip that.
For `6` all pair of factors are:

```
1,2  =>already edge exists with weight f[2] so will skip
1,3  =>already edge exists with weight f[3] so will skip
1,6  =>draw edge with weight f[6]
2,3  =>draw edge with weight f[6]
2,6  =>draw edge with weight f[6]
3,6  =>draw edge with weight f[6]
```

**Tiangle counting:**

Note Neither for `I:` labeled values nor for `3B:` labeled values the graph is required. The graph is being constructed for `6A:` values

`mark[c]` denotes wheather it has been traversed earlier as first distance. if yes it has value equal to weight of edge used to traverse to it.
[image]

Before traversing node `a`, for each edge incident on a we mark the source node in by weight and clear it once traversing `a` case is complete. So `mark[c]` to have a valid value node `x` has to be node `a`. Hence `a` triangle.

[image]

`w1 * w2 * mark[c]` is equivalent to `w1 * w2 * wc`

The overall Time complexity = O(n+E +[E^1.5](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823650/1068604))

=$O(n+nlogn+(nlogn)^{1.5})$

for n=1000000, its around = $O(n+10n+430n)$ = $4*10^8$

Since median of factors of a number is its square root we managed to get a sparse graph, so time complexity is order of $(nlogn)^{1.5}$ .
If graph was dense ie $E=n^2$ then triangle finding is $O(n^3)$ when we arrive at complexity similar to @mike-earnest 's answer. Conversely if you substitute $n^{0.5}$ for $n$ in @mike-earnest 's answer you get complexity similar to this.

Comment: The formula on OEIS seems to be a little bit broken. Possibly the issue is that we're using the wrong upper bound on $a,b,c$ in the sum, but I don't see a choice for that upper bound that gives the right answer, and I don't think the sum converges without an upper bound.

Comment: @misha-lavrov Eric Towers tried to answer it as a part of little different question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/851012/1068604)  . He is also talking about constructing graph. His graph is quite trivial which doesn't decrease time complexity unlike the one which Reyna & Heyman are talking about . If you have gone through the paper let me know if you understand how they are constructing the graph.

Answer (score 2):

The OEIS formula is mistaken. To fix it, replace all instances of `gcd` with `lcm`. This code prints `13` when run.

```
from math import gcd

def lcm(a,b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)

mu = [0, 1, -1, -1]

N = 3    
accum = 0
for a in range(1, N + 1):
    for b in range(1, N + 1):
        for c in range(1, N + 1):
            accum += (
                  mu[a] 
                * mu[b] 
                * mu[c] 
                * (N // lcm(a, b))
                * (N // lcm(a, c))
                * (N // lcm(b, c))
                )
print('number of triples = ', accum)
```

Comment: Thanks mike . Did you get a chance to look at more efficent ways to compute ie Reyna & Heyman's paper linked there. I am here more for that. I can't make much of it no matter how hard I try.

Comment: @MasrukaJannat What precisely are you looking for in an answer? Code to compute the number of triples? I do not understand the paper, but I can tell the paper is not helpful for computing the number of triples.

Comment: I need to compute for n of order of 1 million . So this wont suffice. this is O(n^3*log(n)). probably its possible something like O(n^2*log(n)) or maybe better if we go by that paper.

Comment: It's constructing the graph in something like O(n*logn*logn) and then next pass at around O(n*summation_deg(ai)^2). I am not sure of the exact complexity, but I think it's below quadratic.

Comment: I do not see how you are getting any sort of time estimate from the paper. You understand that in this problem, the graph would have three vertices, with three edges between every pair (because we require (a,b), (b,c), and (a,c) to all be coprime), right? Therefore, any graph you build will take constant time. Furthermore, it seems like the paper is computing nothing exactly; everything has an error term.

Comment: did you read the link to the other answer. There someone talks of being able to do it till 1 million in one sec and thats [2012](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?t=2889) which is before Hu's paper and before Reyna & Heyman's paper. 1 million in 1 sec error essentially means O(n*log n) or similar

Comment: Yes that's what I want to understand . Someone who implemented the paper are gettting the exact value without errors. I dont understand why they are talking about error in a deterministic approach. You are assuming all integers are nodes and all edges are their relationship ie co-primality or gcd. It may not be the case. the weight of edge i seems to be number of multiples of integer i till n and end points seem to be some kind of factor of i or some kind of factor multiple of i or some kind of factor of (multiple of i)/i. its a sparse graph, construction time proportional to no of edges

Comment: @MasrukaJannat In the [discussion you linked](https://projecteuler.chat/viewtopic.php?t=2889), they are not claiming they can count _pairwise coprime_ triples for $N=10^6$ in under a second. Anyway, I think I am not able to help you, but I hope you can find your algorithm.

Comment: [This](https://ideone.com/QuEKuU) is an implementation I found. His answer matches with [A256390](https://oeis.org/A256390) and he is doing 1 million in 6 sec. I dont understand his code either. Maybe you can take a quick peak. if you are better at understanding code maybe you would be able to do better job than me in understanding it.